# Use memcache for Rails.cache in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I configure the Rails.cache to use memcache in development? By default is writting in tmp folder, but I want it to use memcache.

Where should I write that config?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to look into the [dalli](https://github.com/mperham/dalli) gem for that.

[Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-memcached-with-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts) is a guide to help you set it up. [This](http://vinsol.com/blog/2014/02/11/guide-to-caching-in-rails-using-memcache/) is also a good resource.

You can also have a look at [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/380-memcached-dalli) execellent screencast from Ryan to get you started.

I could simply post the one line configuration snippet you need to add to the `development.rb` file but I am afraid it is not that simple.